# Finding points $B$ and $D$ of a square, given points $A$ and $C$

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a square in the $xy$-plane. The coordinates of points $A$ and $C$ are $(1,2)$ and $(2,-2)$, respectively. Could someone show me how to find the remaining two points $B$ and $D$, using an 'algebraic' approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint1:

$AC$ is a diagonal of the square. The other two points $B,D$ are on the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ at the same distance as $A$ and $C$ from the midpoint of $AC$.

Hint 2:

the midpoint $P$ of $AC$ has coordinates $P=(\frac{3}{2},0)$ and the vector that goes from $P$ to $A$ has components $\overrightarrow{PA}=[-\frac{1}{2},2]$, so two orthogonal vectors with the same length are 
$$
\left[-2,-\frac{1}{2}\right] \qquad \left[2,\frac{1}{2}\right]
$$

Can you find $B$ and $D$ from these?

Comment: maybe is better ''belong to the axis'' ( my english is poor), but this is more that the perpendicular, it is the perpendicular at the midpoint.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "perpendicular bisector" of $AC$.

Comment: OK, thank! in Italian it is ''asse'' :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is find two equations of points that are satisfied by both $B$ and $D$, but no other points. For example the properties that $|\vec{AP}| = |\vec{CP}|$ and $\vec{AP} \cdot \vec{CP} = 0$ are simultaneously satisfied for $P$ if and only iff $P = B$ or $P = D$.

Comment: Do you mean $\vec{AP}$ $x$ $\vec{CP}$ $=$ $0$ ?

Comment: No, I do mean $\vec{AP} \cdot \vec{CP} = 0$, which is true exactly when those two vectors are orthogonal. This is the case exactly when $P$ lies on the Thales circle over $A$ and $C$.

Comment: Also you can write a $\times$ with \times.